# What´s wrong with this MDX query?

Tags: mdx, data-warehouse

I tried to execute this query and i can´t understand what´s wrong with it.

```
 SELECT {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],
         [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]} ON COLUMNS,
 [Product].[Product].[Product].Members ON ROWS
 FROM [AdventureWorks2008R2]
```

I get error message:

```
 Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
 Incorrect syntax near 'Measures'.
```

I thought it was the "{}" and changed them for "()" instead, then i got this message:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

--- EDIT
I was at the wrong place writing the query but now i get this other message:

```
Executing the query ...
Query (3, 10) The MEMBERS function expects a hierarchy expression for the  argument.  A member expression was used.

Execution complete
```

The query:

```
SELECT {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ,
        [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]} ON COLUMNS,
       {[Product].[Product].[Product].Members} ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Comment: This is just Multidimensional expression syntax - you are running this against a cube right? This isn't SQL...

Comment: not sure if the space is needed between the curly braces.

Comment: Please change the question title to say "What's wrong with this MDX Query?" Also, what system are you using? Microsoft? You may want to mention this in the question as well.

Comment: yes i am on ssas, (and on microsoft). I have started a trace and want to see what´s happening when doing the mdx query..

Comment: "Expects a hierarchy expression" - You may get this error if the AttributeHierarchyEnabled property is set to false for the attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nothing wrong with query.
i think you run the query against sql db .not Analysis service db
.please right click on ssas db adventurework an run the query.

Answer (score 0):

The brackets are breaking the query in the first instance, since the statement is not valid SQL. The bigger problem is that you aren't writing SQL, you are writing MDX, so your syntax is wrong.

Did you want to have a Hierarchize in there somewhere? Also, are you selecting from a database, or a table? (I can't tell, but you need to change the end `From []` to select from what you want.)

```
SELECT
Hierarchize({[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount], [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]}) ON COLUMNS,
Hierarchize({[Product].[Product].[Product].Members}) ON ROWS 
FROM [AdventureWorks2008R2]
```

Comment: when i use above question with "adventure works" i get error: Query (3, 53) Parser: The syntax for 'ON' is incorrect.

Comment: You are asking a new question. You should ask it as a new question... If you tag it properly the first time, and use a good question title, people who are MDX experts may actually be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is with 
this expression

```
[Product].[Product].[Product].Members
```

and espcially second and third '[Product]'
i think in your code maby you put some space or ..[Product ] the Product.
check for correctnes

i suggest drag this member from Cube explorer .
maybe it helps!!